# Как воспроизвести аудио файл Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Мне нужно воспроизвести аудио файл при получении сообщения у получателя.

```
class MessageBroadcastJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(message)
    sender = message.profile
    recipient = message.conversation.opposed_profile(sender)

    broadcast_to_sender(sender, message)
    broadcast_to_recipient(recipient, message)
  end

  private

  def broadcast_to_sender(profile, message)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast(
      "conversations-#{profile.id}",
      message: render_message(message, profile),
      conversation_id: message.conversation_id
    )
  end

  def broadcast_to_recipient(profile, message)
    # Здесь нужно сделать воспроизведение аудио файла
    ActionCable.server.broadcast(
      "conversations-#{profile.id}",
      window: render_window(message.conversation, profile),
      message: render_message(message, profile),
      conversation_id: message.conversation_id
    )
  end

  def render_message(message, profile)
    ApplicationController.render(
      partial: 'messages/message',
      locals: { message: message, profile: profile }
    )
  end

  def render_window(conversation, profile)
    ApplicationController.render(
      partial: 'conversations/conversation',
      locals: { conversation: conversation, profile: profile }
    )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я решил данный вопрос другим способом

```
var conversation = $('#conversations-list').find("[data-conversation-id='" + data['conversation_id'] + "']");

if (data['window'] !== undefined) {
  $('#messageAudio').trigger("play");
  conversation.find('.messages-list').find('ul').append(data['message']);
}
else {
  conversation.find('ul').append(data['message']);
}
```